# react-router and flux how to?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, reactjs-flux

I try to interact with data on route changes(I use react-router 1.0.0) but inherited components are not fetching data from API

basically I have my base route which is interacting with the store but the inherited route like `/:slug` does not updates the component with new data

it seems like the `_onChange` will not fire up!
the component

```
import React from 'react';
import PropertyStore from '../stores/PropertyStore';
import AppActions from '../actions/AppActions'



class Property extends React.Component{

    constructor(){
        super();
        this.state = {
            property: []
        }

        this._onChange = this._onChange.bind(this);
        this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);

    }

    componentWillMount(){
        PropertyStore.addChangeListener(this._onChange);
    }

    componentWillUnmount() {
        PropertyStore.removeChangeListener(this._onChange);
    }

    componentDidMount () {
        AppActions.getProperty( this.props.params.slug );
    }

    handleChange(e) {}

    _onChange() {
        this.setState({
            property: PropertyStore.getProperty( this.props.params.slug )
        });
    }

    render() {
        var property;
        if (this.state.property) {
            console.log(this.state.property) //empty!!

            property = this.state.property.map(function (detail, i) {
        return (
            <div>{detail.description}</div>)
            });
        }

        return(
            <div className="Property"> {property} </div>
        )
    }
}


module.exports = Property;
```

AppActions

```
'use strict';

var AppDispatcher = require('../dispatchers/AppDispatcher');
var AppConstants = require('../constants/AppConstants');
var PropertiesStore = require('../stores/PropertiesStore');
var PropertyStore = require('../stores/PropertyStore');
var Promise = require('es6-promise').Promise; // jshint ignore:line
var Api = require('../services/Api');

var AppActions = {

    getProperties: function () {
        Api
            .get('/api/v2/properties')
            .then(function (properties) {
                AppDispatcher.handleViewAction({
                    actionType: AppConstants.RECEIVE_PROPERTIES,
                    properties: properties.data.properties
                });
            })
            .catch(function () {
                AppDispatcher.handleViewAction({
                    actionType: AppConstants.RECEIVE_ERROR,
                    error: 'There was a problem getting the workshops'
                });
            });
    },

    getProperty: function (slug) {

        Api
            .get('/api/v2/properties/'+ slug)
            .then(function (property) {

                AppDispatcher.handleViewAction({
                    actionType: AppConstants.RECEIVE_PROPERTY,
                    property: property.data.property
                });
            })
            .catch(function () {
                AppDispatcher.handleViewAction({
                    actionType: AppConstants.RECEIVE_ERROR,
                    error: 'There was a problem getting the Voucher'
                });
            });

    },

    getMedia: function () {
        Api
            .get('/wp-json/wp/v2/workshops')
            .then(function (workshops) {
                AppDispatcher.handleViewAction({
                    actionType: WorkshopConstants.RECEIVE_MEDIA,
                    workshops: workshops
                });
            })
            .catch(function () {
                AppDispatcher.handleViewAction({
                    actionType: WorkshopConstants.RECEIVE_ERROR,
                    error: 'There was a problem getting the categories'
                });
            });
    }

};

module.exports = AppActions;
```

Comment: More context is needed to provide a solution. Is the AppActions.getProperty returning a value? Is the store correctly populated? How does the Router interact with the component?

Comment: I added my AppActions. Yes AppActions is returning data from API if I log inside promise