# Simple usage example of react-router with flux

Tags: reactjs, react-router, flux

Is there a simple example which shows how to use react-router with flux?
I have been searching around and I found this repo [flux-react-router-example](https://github.com/gaearon/flux-react-router-example) which is quite complex to get the idea behind, how different routes should be mapped by Flux. I understand that should be used a proxy store for routes but is not clear.

is there a simple example somewhere?

and yeah Happy New Year!!

Comment: You'll need a pro account, but I suspect this might meed your needs: https://egghead.io/lessons/react-react-flux-routing-with-react-router-component

Comment: Do you have a specific question about using the two together? Implementing both of them you shouldn't really run into issues where one affects the other.

Comment: my problem I do not know how to fetch data on route changes when trying to interact with API and is this question is related to my other question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34511849/react-router-and-flux-how-to?noredirect=1#comment56765245_34511849